# Android canvas load bmp on click button

Tags: android

i have a layout for drawing content_designer.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/loadBMP"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Load"/>
    <com.system.v.construct.Drawing
        android:id="@+id/canvasDraw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In my activity i set the view and whe user click the button bmp must be loaded.

```
       setContentView(R.layout.content_designer);
    Button load=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loadBMP);

    final Drawing drawing=new Drawing(this);
    load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            drawing.looadBMP();
        }
    });
```

In drawing class i have a method looadBMP()

But the image doesnt load, i'm beginner in drawing, so sorry for mistake

Here is a full Drawin class seems like method on Draw is executed first, i need bmp image load on button click:

```
public class Drawing extends View implements OnTouchListener {
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
public Paint mPaint;
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
Bitmap bmp;
public static Canvas myCanvas;

public Drawing(Context context) {
    super(context);


}
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

public void looadBMP()
{

    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.simple);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(mPath);
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, mPaint);
    for (Path p : paths) {
        mCanvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;
//Drawing dw = new Drawing();

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;

}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(mPath);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide the full code for the Drawing class. And why you create a new Drawing(this) and not getting it by id? findViewById(R.id.canvasDraw)

Comment: I create a new Drawing(this because i need to call loadBMP()

Comment: can you post the log or error you're getting

Comment: If you create a new Dwawing(this) than this View is not attached to the screen, that is why you even do not see it. And you do not use Drawing that is in the layout. You need get it by id and than you can call loadBMP()

Comment: i didn't get any kind of error

Comment: So how i can youse in method loadBMP canvas from onDraw(Canvas canvas)? Thanks